# Handling files with dynamic data structures with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, csv, spring-boot, spring-batch

My current project has roughly seven years of csv files that were generated daily, and I've found out that as the years past, the column structure has changed. Every reader that I've done in the past has hard coded column names, so I'm wondering if there's a way to read the column names of the current file being written, and map it to a corresponding object for use later on for processing.